# How to use .win.dll C# wrapper (FatSecret API Wrapper)

Tags: c#, dll, wrapper

I've delved into trying to use the FatSecret REST API directly from code, but getting it to work correctly has been pretty difficult. On my quest to get it working I ran into a FatSecret C# wrapper that looked appealing, found here:

https://fatsecretsharp.codeplex.com/

When I downloaded the folder from that site I found two files:
- FatSecretSharp.Win.dll
- FatSecretSharp.Win

What I wonder is how to actually include these files in a C# project and start using the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to go to solution references and add the win.dll.